# Chart.js labels filtering

Tags: charts

I'm using Chart.js but have too many labels on the x-axis. Does anyone know if I can filter out the labels? There is a 2013 version of Chart.js that does it but I have the 2015 one and the two are very different. My code already depends on the 2015 one.

So basically, is there a 2015 version of Chart.js where the x-axis labels can be filtered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the way out. If you go into Chart.min.js and find:

```
calculateXLabelRotation : function(){ 

...

if (this.display){ ... } else { ... }

...

}
```

Comment out the entire if-else statement. That will disable labelRotation for the horizontal scale. This means the labels will no longer rotate if they lack space.

Then, when you pass an array for:

```
var lineData = {
    labels: someArrayOfLabels
... 
}
```

Just pass empty values ("") at the positions you don't want a label to appear. This means that labels that do appear will take up as much space as they need.